# Files list returned by os.walk is not in any discernible order

Tags: python, list, file, file-attributes

Is there any way to sort the list of file names returned by os.walk such that it returns a list that is from youngest file to oldest file? Im trying to write a code that deletes files after a certain amount of time.

Here's what i have:

```
import os
import time
import shutil
from pathlib import pathlib
os.chdir("/home/pi/Videos")

while True:
    for root, files in os.walk(".", topdown = True)
        for name in files:
            f = os.path.join(root, name)
            print(f)

    st = os.stat(f)
    age = time.time()-st.st_mtime)
    print(age)
    if age > 200
       os.remove(f)
    time.sleep(1)
```

This works to delete any files in a folder, but if the file in question is not old enough to be deleted it will wait until the file can be deleted until it can move on to the next file. This is a problem. D:<
I've tried to use the shutil, pathlib, and os libraries to move the file from the folder it is in back into the folder it's in, but it doesn't change anything. ):< I'm out of knowledge of libraries.(im new)

I either need to organize the list returned by the os.walk() method so that the oldest are at the bottom (or top it doesnt matter) or have a way to skip the file if the file is underage. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. :D

Comment: Because of indentation, your code is only look at the last file in the directory structure. Is this intentional? Is it practical for your case to make a list of all files with `os.walk` and then you can sort via `list_of_files=sorted(list_of_files,key=os.path.getmtime)`?

Comment: What is the purpose of the while loop?

Comment: @jpf No, it is not intentional. I don't have a good grasp on how a lot of this works. The only thing I know that has to do with the last file in the directory structure is setting the topdown value = to True or False.  Let me try what you suggested. ill get back with updates.

Comment: @NaN The code within the while loop, when run, will only check if the file is old enough to be deleted, and delete once.  the while loop in my eyes lets it move onto the next file. if you have any suggestions to streamline that im all ears.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thanks to @jpf, but i had to totally rework my code based on their suggestion. As stated in the question my ultimate goal is a code that deletes files that are older than x amount of time.

Here is the code that i came up with based on the suggestion.

```
import os
import time
os.chdir("/home/pi/Videos")
max_age = 50000 #this sets the maximum age of the files
while True:
    list_of_files = os.listdir() #returns list of all files in a folder
    sorted_list = sorted(list_of_files,key = os.path.getmtime)#sorts list based on age
    file = sorted_list[0] #defines oldest file in list
    st = os.stat(file) 
    age = (time.time() - st.st_mtime) #returns age of file in seconds by subtracting time since epoch from time of file metadata change
    print(file,"is",age,"seconds old")
    if age > max_age: #checks if file is older than max_age 
         print(file,"is older than ",max_age," seconds old") #if older prints this statement and deletes the file
         os.remove(file)
    else   #if younger then the loop breaks
         break
```

This code uses os.listdir to return the file names in a list. 
Then I used sorted to sort that list from oldest to youngest
Then I started the deletion process from oldest to youngest, breaking when the file age was too young to delete.

Comment: The difference between `os.walk` and `os.listdir` is that the first returns all files from all subdirectories, whereas the latter returns only the current directory's files. If it is desirable to still see all files from all subdirectories, you can use `os.walk` as you had it before, but make sure your loop is `for root,dirs,name in os.walk('.',topdown=True)` and then instead of `print(f)` just do `list_of_files.append(f)` after having initialized `list_of_files=[]`. Then you can sort it as you've done.